# SAPUI5 Smartfields in extension project

Tags: sapui5

I have a working application(A) which makes use of SmartFields in the XML.
I created an extension project based on this working application, my working application (A) still works fine and all data is displayed as expected.

But when I run my extension project:
My SmartFields used in the application (A) only display the label and the bound value is not shown, even though if I use my UI5-Inspector, the value contains data.

Even the SmartFields that I created in my extension project (I created an extension point for an extra fragment which contains SmartFields), only show the label and not the value that I inserted:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.uxap" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:m="sap.m"
xmlns:suite="sap.suite.ui.commons" xmlns:comp="sap.ui.comp.variants" xmlns:smartForm="sap.ui.comp.smartform"
xmlns:smartField="sap.ui.comp.smartfield">
<ObjectPageSection title="{i18n_AfkoppelingsDossier>tab.Project}" id="projectTab-ObjectPageSection--id">
    <subSections>
        <ObjectPageSubSection>
            <blocks>
                <smartForm:SmartForm id="ProjectSmartFormId" editable="true">
                    <!-- Kolom 1 -->
                    <smartForm:Group label="{i18n_AfkoppelingsDossier>title.project}">
                            <smartForm:GroupElement useHorizontalLayout="true">
                            <m:Input value="abc"/>
                        </smartForm:GroupElement>
                        <smartForm:GroupElement>
                            <smartField:SmartField id="IDWBSElement" textLabel="{i18n_AfkoppelingsDossier>label.WBS.element}" value="a"/>
                        </smartForm:GroupElement>
                        <smartForm:GroupElement useHorizontalLayout="true">
                            <smartField:SmartField id="IDContractNumber" textLabel="{i18n_AfkoppelingsDossier>label.contrNr.contractor}" value="nummerke"/>
                        </smartForm:GroupElement>
                        <smartForm:GroupElement useHorizontalLayout="true">
                            <smartField:SmartField id="IDMaxIntervention" textLabel="{i18n_AfkoppelingsDossier>label.max.intervention}" value="0.00€"/>
                        </smartForm:GroupElement>
                        <smartForm:GroupElement useHorizontalLayout="true">
                            <smartField:SmartField id="IDLocationInfomeeting" textLabel="{i18n_AfkoppelingsDossier>label.location.infomeeting}" value="Locatie"/>
                        </smartForm:GroupElement>
                    </smartForm:Group>
                </smartForm:SmartForm>
            </blocks>
        </ObjectPageSubSection>
    </subSections>
</ObjectPageSection>
```

I've inspected my DevTools and the valueis there, so I have no clue why it doesn't display the value.

Properties of SmartField:
[image]

Any ideas on what might cause this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please do not screenshot your code, it is a bad practice. Please include your code in the post :)

Comment: Maybe this has to do with `css`? if the value is there as you say using devtools...

Comment: @eibersji done, sorry :)

Comment: @OlayinkaO I didn't change any css, the value is shown in the properties, but the value isn't shown in my DOM.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you could try playing around with css in devtools to see where its hidden or use **`CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S`** to use `control tree`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate this and it seems the `value property` only works with bindings.

[Value Control Property Definition](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField/controlProperties)

&

[SmateField Example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield/preview)

The data.json and view.xml File:

```js
[{

  "nummerke": "nummerke",
  "Euro": "0.00€",
  "Local": "Locatie",
  "Letter": "a"
}]
```

```html
<mvc:View controllerName="com.controller.name" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:smartForm="sap.ui.comp.smartform" xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data" xmlns:suite="sap.suite.ui.commons"
  xmlns:comp="sap.ui.comp.variants" xmlns:smartField="sap.ui.comp.smartfield">
  <Page id="page" title="PageTitle" showHeader="true" enableScrolling="true">
    <content>
      <FlexBox alignItems="Center" busyIndicatorDelay="{masterView>/delay}" renderType="Bare" class="ne-flexbox2" width="100%" justifyContent="SpaceBetween" id="container">
        <items>
          <smartForm:SmartForm id="ProjectSmartFormId" editable="true">
            <!-- Kolom 1 -->
            <smartForm:Group label="title.project">
              <smartForm:GroupElement useHorizontalLayout="true">
                <Input value="abc" />
              </smartForm:GroupElement>
              <smartForm:GroupElement>
                <smartField:SmartField id="IDWBSElement" value="{/0/Letter}" />
              </smartForm:GroupElement>
              <smartForm:GroupElement useHorizontalLayout="true">
                <smartField:SmartField id="IDContractNumber" textLabel="label.contrNr.contractor" value="{nummerke}" />
              </smartForm:GroupElement>
              <smartForm:GroupElement useHorizontalLayout="true">
                <smartField:SmartField id="IDMaxIntervention" textLabel="label.max.intervention" value="{/0/Euro}" />
              </smartForm:GroupElement>
              <smartForm:GroupElement useHorizontalLayout="true">
                <smartField:SmartField id="IDLocationInfomeeting" textLabel="label.location.infomeeting" value="{/0/Local}" />
              </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
          </smartForm:SmartForm>
        </items>
      </FlexBox>
    </content>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help Olayinka, I have decided to make use of a Simple Form instead of the SmartFields. 

With bindings my data is shown in my main application (was already the case).
But in my extension application, the value is somehow not displayed even though it is definately bound to the SmartField.

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)